# How to use Pinia with defineCustomElement in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, store, custom-element, pinia

is it possible to use the pinia store in a component as an element?

try doing it this way but i get the following error in developer console

```
index.8ec3cfca.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_s')
```

**pinia store**

```
import { UsuarioInternet } from "../../models/UsuariosInternet.model"
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useFAUsuarioInternet = defineStore("useFAUsuarioInternet",{
    
        state:() => ({
            items: <UsuarioInternet[]>([])
        }),
    
        getters:{
             listaUsuario(state){
                return state.items;
             }   
        },
    
        actions:{
            createNewUser(item :UsuarioInternet){
                if(!item) return;
                this.items.push(item);
            },
            findIndexById(id: number){
                return this.items.findIndex((item) => item.id == id);
            }
        }
    })
```

**component**

```
<template>
    <p>
        setsetsetestset
    </p>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup >    
      import { ref , onMounted, computed} from 'vue';
      import { useFAUsuarioInternet } from "../stores/general/useFAUsuariosInternet";
      import { UsuarioInternet } from "../models/UsuariosInternet.model";

      let Usuario = ref<UsuarioInternet>(new UsuarioInternet);
            
      //mounted  
      onMounted(() => {
      });

      const mainStore = useFAUsuarioInternet();

      //call action      
     const saveUser = () => {
       mainStore.createNewUser(Usuario.value);
     }
    
      //getters
     const lista = computed(() => mainStore.listaUsuario)
</script>
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { createApp, defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import UsuariosInternet from './pages/general/UsuariosInternet.ce.vue'
import homeTest from './components/homeTest.ce.vue'

const element = defineCustomElement(UsuariosInternet);
customElements.define("usuarios-internet", element);

const element2 = defineCustomElement(homeTest);
customElements.define('home-test', element2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `main.ts` you want:

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from "vue";
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia";
import UsuariosInternet from "./pages/general/UsuariosInternet.ce.vue";
import homeTest from "./components/homeTest.ce.vue";

// Here you create a standalone pinia
setActivePinia(createPinia());

const element = defineCustomElement(UsuariosInternet);
customElements.define("usuarios-internet", element);

const element2 = defineCustomElement(homeTest);
customElements.define("home-test", element2);
```

This will create a global store for all your components.

See: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1085#discussioncomment-2219587